# Obstacle wont move

Tags: actionscript-3

I cannot understand why the items in my array won't move down the stage along the y axis, I want them to appear randomly across the x. Here is my code:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

public class obstacleOne extends MovieClip {
    private var speed:Number;
    private var obstacleOneTypes:Array = ["obstacle1","obstacle2"];
    private var thisObstacleOneType:String;

    public function obstacleOne() {
        // constructor code
        // pick a random number between 1 and the amount of types of litter
        var randomNumber:uint = Math.ceil(Math.random() * obstacleOneTypes.length);
        thisObstacleOneType = obstacleOneTypes[randomNumber - 1];
        this.gotoAndStop(randomNumber);
        this.x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 400);
        this.y =0 - Math.random()*400;
        speed = 4 + (Math.random()*4)
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,updateMe);
    }

    public function caught():void{
        // in this function are going to animate the litter removing from the screen using a tween equation
        // when it is finished we can remove the object
        // now place in a random position on the beach
        this.x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * stage.stageWidth);
        this.y =0 - Math.random()*2000;
    }

    private function updateMe(evt:Event):void{
        this.y += speed;
        if(y>stage.stageHeight){
            this.y = 7;
            // send an event to main class to subtract score
            //stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("hitBottom",true));
        }//*/
    }
```

Comment: If you found the solution to your problem please provide it here such that others with the same problem can benefit from this. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I put the class in a package named "ch" and then have in the main timeline:

```
import ch.obstacleOne;

stage.addChild(new obstacleOne());
stage.addChild(new obstacleOne());
stage.addChild(new obstacleOne());
stage.addChild(new obstacleOne());
```

The class is as before:

```
package ch{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

public class obstacleOne extends MovieClip {
....
```

Then you need to connect a movieclip in the library with your class (Sorry GUI is in German):

[image: Screenshot]

Should work then.